# Memory jumps on GPU when jitting functions in JAX

Tags: memory-leaks, gpu, simulation, jit, jax

I am currently trying to prepare hundreds of simulations of different molecules of various sizes by jitting the functions used to run the simulations on a single GPU with `JAX`. I essentially do this iteratively in a `for` loop. In doing so, the memory exhibits jumps at seemingly random points

[image]

where each update represents each molecule simulation function getting jitted. The jumps happen instantly i.e. between two updates. I thought to perhaps try functions like `jax.clear_backends()` or `jax.clear_caches()` at the 100th update to try mitigate this behaviour, however, using `jax.clear_backends()` seems to worsen the issue, as below

[image]

and `jax.clear_caches()` just kills the process and the core gets dumped.

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You mention running through multiple simulations via a `for` loop; I assume this is not within any `jit`-compiled function, but rather at the top level.

If that is the case, then you may be running into the effects of JAX's [Asynchronous dispatch](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async_dispatch.html). Briefly, suppose your code looks something like this

```py
inputs: list[jax.Array] = get_inputs()
outputs: list[jax.Array] = []

for x in inputs:
  outputs.append(expensive_jax_computation(x))
```

The `for` loop will dispatch all the inputs asynchronously, meaning that the second computation may start before the first finishes, and would utilize the GPU resources in parallel.

You could check whether this is the case by blocking each iteration:

```py
for x in inputs:
  outputs.append(jax.block_until_ready(expensive_jax_computation(x)))
```

This would ensure that each iteration finishes completely before the next iteration starts.

Comment: Many thanks @jakevdp for your answer! This sounds very promising and am currently working on fitting this in. But a quick sanity check - what I didn't mention is that once all the functions are jit-compiled and the loop gets repeated, the memory no longer significantly increases - is that in line with your thinking that it could have something to do with asynchronous dispatch?

Comment: Using `jax.block_until_ready()`doesn't seem to fix the memory jumps, but nonetheless very good to have that in mind! I don't suppose you may have any other inklings to the root cause?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this answer may be relevant to your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74631949